# Create a list of article titles by subcategory

Tags: joomla-3.3.x

So, this is what I'm trying to do:

Category (News)

Subcategory 1 (Sports)

Article Title 1 (Story Title)

Article Title 2 (Story Title)

Article title 3 (Story Title)

Subcategory 2 (Fashion)

Article Title 4 (Story Title)

Article Title 5 (Story Title)

Article Title 6 (Story Title)

I feel like I must be missing something really obvious, because this seems ridiculously difficult to do. The closest I have gotten displays not just the article titles, but also the entire article text.

I know I could do it manually, but I'd really prefer not to as it would be a lot of maintenance.

Help!

Answer (score 2):

You don't miss something really obvious. The truth is that this type of article display is not included in the core content component.

But you are lucky here. There are a few extensions that will make your life easier with this , than having to code this at your own within an override, and the good news is that they are free.

My first recommendation is the [**SectionX by StackIdeas**](http://stackideas.com/downloads/components). It's coming as a component and will allow you to create a menu item and adjust the settings to display it the way you want.

There is one more component "[**SectionCategoryArticleList**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-listing/19418)", which comes also as a [**module**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-listing/22931) with similar functionality.

Comment: Hi: Thanks for the suggestions. It seems like SectionX isn't available for my version of Joomla, but SectionCategoryArticleList does sort of work. I just can't figure out where to edit the display defaults - I can't tell where they're inherited from, and editing the extension's CSS file seems to have no effect. But anyway that's a question for the developer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's your joomla version?

Comment: 3.3.6 stable...

Comment: xSection works in 3.3.6.